# MassTransit not using XmlDeserializer

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

### MassTransit.RabbitMQ 4.0.0.1334-develop on netcoreapp2.0

It appears MassTransit is still trying to use the JsonDeserializer, even when the incoming message has a content_type of `application/vnd.masstransit+xml`.  My assumption (possibly wrong) is that MassTransit will use the correct deserializer based on the incoming **content_type** header.

**Note: I am testing this by sending a message into the exchange directly in RabbitMQ Management Console.**

Error is:

```
MT-Reason:  fault
MT-Fault-Message:   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
MT-Fault-Timestamp: 2017-11-14T22:28:23.9008730Z
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageDeserializer.MassTransit.IMessageDeserializer.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext)
```

I have configured my receive endpoint (from Castle Windsor container) with the following code:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "my-consumer", ep =>
{
  ep.UseMessageScope();
  ep.LoadFrom(container);
});
```

Additional things I have tried:

1.

```
ep.UseXmlSerializer();
```

2.

```
ep.AddEndpointSpecification(new SupportMessageDeserializerReceiveEndpointSpecification(XmlMessageSerializer.XmlContentType, () => new XmlMessageDeserializer(XmlMessageSerializer.XmlSerializer)));
```

3.

```
ep.AddEndpointSpecification(new SupportMessageDeserializerReceiveEndpointSpecification(XmlMessageSerializer.XmlContentType, () => new XmlMessageDeserializer(JsonMessageSerializer.Deserializer)));
```

4.

```
sbc.UseXmlSerializer();
```

None of those seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - 
MassTransit does not use the standard RabbitMq *property* of `content_type`, but instead uses a *header* called `Content-Type`